# libgdx - error while trying to use ShapeRenderer

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make a fade in effect using ShapeRenderer with this code:

```
            Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
            Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            //ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;

            shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(stage.getCamera().combined);
            shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
            shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,fadeTimeElapsed/1.5f));
            shapeRenderer.rect(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            shapeRenderer.end();

            Gdx.gl20.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
```

I get the following exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2715
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no uniform with name 'u_projModelView' in shader
>               at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.fetchUniformLocation(ShaderProgram.java:287)
>               at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.fetchUniformLocation(ShaderProgram.java:277)
>               at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.setUniformMatrix(ShaderProgram.java:507)
>               at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.setUniformMatrix(ShaderProgram.java:498)
>               at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.flush(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:147)
>               at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.end(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:160)
>               at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.end(ShapeRenderer.java:1104)
>               at net.ukk.rpg.Level.render(Level.java:93)
>               at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
>               at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:422)
>               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1542)
>               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1266)

BTW with `ShaderProgram.pedantic=false`, I don't get any filled rectangle.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code that sets up its own shader or otherwise changes the default shader?

Comment: No, not that i know. But I'm new to libgdx, so I don't know what could change the default shader automatically.

Comment: You're probably okay on the shader.  Do you have any other in-progress OpenGL (e.g., an active `SpriteBatch` or other construct that has a `begin`/`end` like the shapeRenderer does)?

Comment: I am drawing a Stage before the code. Nothing that has a begin/end anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I was instantiating the ShapeRenderer in a Thread. Calling the constructor in the `show()` method solved the issue.

Comment: ah, thanks for answering your own question!  Android (and Libgdx) only support a single thread with OpenGL, so most of the API expects everything to be done on the render thread.

Comment: I had the same problem. You can also call the constructor in a Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() ...); call.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same crash when I called my method (showAxesTicks) on UI thread that eventually called shapeRenderer.end(). I resolved it by embracing showAxesTicks() inside Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() ...) as @user1702985 mentioned. I think it causes the functions to get ran on the same OpenGL thread:

------------BEFORE CHANGE----------------

```
public void onGridMarkersMetricSelected() {
    mLibgdxFragment.showAxesTicks(true);

    hDebugConsole.consoleLog(TAG, "User enabled Metric Grid Markers");
    return;
}
```

------------AFTER CHANGE----------------

```
public void onGridMarkersMetricSelected() {
    Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mLibgdxFragment.showAxesTicks(true);                
        }
    });
    hDebugConsole.consoleLog(TAG, "User enabled Metric Grid Markers");
    return;
}
```